# how to print ros1 bag data output on ros2

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
How can I print the output of ros1.bag file in ros2…
while I use below command to play data of ros1 in ros2

> ros2 bag play -s rosbag_v2 "path-to-ros.bag-file"

I see it is running/playing but i don't see the data which is to be printed on terminal…
while I play the same ros1.bag file in ros1 the output data prints on the terminal… why cant or how can I print this output on the ros2 ??

Kindly answer to my question in a detailed way, as I'am new to this.

Thanks in advance.

Looking forward for the quick reply…

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343016/how-to-print-ros1-bag-data-output-on-ros2/) by [snvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/51351/snvk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I can tell, `ros2 bag play` doesn't provide any status console output. Is currently just `play` the bag file, i.e. reading the data and publishing it to the relevant topics.

There is an open issue about it adding more functionality like the ROS 1 version,: https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/issues/55.
You can comment on it to show your interest in the feature.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/51351/snvk/) on 2020-01-31**:
Thank you for the information :)

**Comment by [snvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/51351/snvk/) on 2020-02-04**:
Hi @marguedas
Just one clarification, is there any defined way or manual way, where I can convert .bag file into .db3 file??
awaiting for your reply and thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2020-02-04**:\

> Just one clarification, is there any defined way or manual way, where I can convert .bag file into .db3 file??

This is a different question, so it should be asked separately.
You will find similar questions that have been answered in the past e.g. https://answers.ros.org/question/314355/conversion-of-rosbag-file-format-to-rosbag2-file-format/

---

> Thank you for the information :)

If the original answer did answer your question please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. This allows other community members to know that this question doesn't need extra eyes.

**Comment by [snvk](https://answers.ros.org/users/51351/snvk/) on 2020-02-04**:
@marguedas thank you